# gethostbyname function returns domain name instead of IP address in PHP

Tags: php, ip-address, gethostbyname

I want to get machine IP address in PHP so i am using function

```
<?php echo gethostbyname($serverName); ?>
```

Its works for all my server machine but it returns domain name for particular IP address for some machine. I don't know why its returning domain name for particular machine and how to get IP address of that particular machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the server name you use wehen this error occurs?

Answer (score 3):

According to [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php)

> Returns the IPv4 address or a string containing the unmodified hostname on failure.

Failure reasons may be couple (e.g. wrong domain name, unreachable host or network problems)

Comment: any other way to get ip address?